# Postgres LEAD(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm facing something like this for the first time, can someone give me a detailed example on how this works? I can't Google any good documentation on this.

```
lead(status_date) OVER (
                           ORDER BY id, status_date
                       )
```

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d1304769f9377045d3ba27039db8c91e

Comment: Why ask Google if the manual has all the information you ask for?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does exist: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows after the current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead return default (which must be of the same type as value). Both offset and default are evaluated with respect to the current row. If omitted, offset defaults to 1 and default to null.